# Using cosmos db for Spring batch job repository

Tags: spring-batch, azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to use CosmosDB as a job repository for Spring Batch?
If that is not possible, can we go with an in-memory DB to handle our Spring batch jobs?
The job itself is triggered on message arrival in a remote queue. We use a variation of the process indicator in our current Spring batch job, to keep track of "chunks" which are being processed. Our attributes for saveStep are also disabled . The reader always uses a DB query to avoid picking up the same chunks and prevent duplicate processing.
We don't commit the message on the queue , till all records for that job are processed. So if the node dies and comes back up in the middle of processing , the same message would be redelivered , which takes of job restarts. Given all this, we have a choice of either coming up with a way to implement a cosmos job repository or simply use in-memory and plug in an "afterJob" listener to clean up the in-memory job data to ensure that java mem is not used in Prod. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to provide information that Azure Cosmos DB just release v3 of the Spring Data connector for the SQL API:

> The Spring on Azure team, in partnership with the Azure Cosmos DB team, are proud to have just made the [Spring Data Azure Cosmos DB v3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-java-spring-v3?tabs=explore) generally available. This is the latest version of Azure Cosmos DB’s SQL API Spring Data connector.

Also, [Spring.io](https://spring.io/blog/2020/09/14/azure-in-the-enterprise-azure-cosmos-db-and-spring-boot) has an example microservices solution ([Spring Cloud Data Flow](https://dataflow.spring.io/getting-started/)) based on batch that could be used as an example for your solution.

**Additional Information:**

- Spring Data Azure Cosmos DB v3 for Core (SQL) API: Release notes and resources ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-java-spring-v3?tabs=explore))
- A well written 3rd party blog that is super helpful:
  Introduction to Spring Data Azure Cosmos DB ([link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-cosmos-db))